# Using Python Pandas to re-organize data from lists into the table

Tags: python, pandas

I have developed a Vehicle Routing (VRP) model that can optimise the route planning by assigning right delivery locations to the right vehicle. The input of my model is a [input.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uvYf62BUn5V58K3eyfEvGlenlrOkkHAP/view?usp=sharing), which can be loaded as a data frame shown below, where each locations are assigned with a unique ID, GPS coordinates and delivery demand. The starting point is the distribution center.

```
  ID  Location_name Location_Lat Location_Lon  Date    Demand
    0       DC      51.4457678  -0.45613      3/4/2016  0
    1   Customer_1  51.799089   -0.29716      3/4/2016  472
    2   Customer_2  52.497911   -1.903832     3/4/2016  1488
    3   Customer_3  53.74589    -2.379778     3/4/2016  5652
    4   Customer_4  52.332395   -1.346753     3/4/2016  2348
    5   Customer_5  52.276323   -1.579845     3/4/2016  12
    6   Customer_6  52.254674   -0.265726     3/4/2016  2940
    7   Customer_7  51.480381   0.332106      3/4/2016  2533
    8   Customer_8  51.466844   -0.452952     3/4/2016  1142
    9   Customer_9  51.714144   -0.462949     3/4/2016  115
    10  Customer_10 50.918412   -0.14951      3/4/2016  325
    11  Customer_11 52.042318   0.311799      3/4/2016  886
    12  Customer_12 52.084242   0.457063      3/4/2016  412
    13  Customer_13 52.126166   0.602327      3/4/2016  58
    14  Customer_14 52.16809    0.747591      3/4/2016  161
    15  Customer_15 52.210014   0.892855      3/4/2016  29
```

Then I run my model and I will get a output (a variable as list of lists):
[[0,8,3,6,11,13,0],[0,12,9,5,0],[0,4,7,10,15,1,14,2,0]]. This means I have to use 3 vehicles:

```
Routes for vehicle 0: [0,8,3,6,11,13,0] #always start and back to DC
Routes for vehicle 1: [0,12,9,5,0] 
Routes for vehicle 2: [0,4,7,10,15,1,14,2,0]
```

Now I want to add a new output function that allows the model to reorganise the above output result in a table format as below:(pay attention to the first/last three rows)

```
ID  Location_name Location_Lat  Location_Lon    Date    demand  Vehicle_ID  Pos_in_routes
0       DC        51.4457678    -0.45613      3/4/2016  0       0           0
0       DC        51.4457678    -0.45613      3/4/2016  0       1           0
0       DC        51.4457678    -0.45613      3/4/2016  0       2           0
1   Customer_1    51.799089     -0.29716      3/4/2016  472     2           5
2   Customer_2    52.497911     -1.903832     3/4/2016  1488    2           7
3   Customer_3    53.74589      -2.379778     3/4/2016  5652    0           2
4   Customer_4    52.332395     -1.346753     3/4/2016  2348    2           1
5   Customer_5    52.276323     -1.579845     3/4/2016  12      1           3
6   Customer_6    52.254674     -0.265726     3/4/2016  2940    0           3
7   Customer_7    51.480381      0.332106     3/4/2016  2533    2           2
8   Customer_8    51.466844     -0.452952     3/4/2016  1142    0           1
9   Customer_9    51.714144     -0.462949     3/4/2016  115     1           2
10  Customer_10   50.918412     -0.14951      3/4/2016  325     2           3
11  Customer_11   52.042318      0.311799     3/4/2016  886     0           4
12  Customer_12   52.084242      0.457063     3/4/2016  412     1           1
13  Customer_13   52.126166      0.602327     3/4/2016  58      0           5
14  Customer_14   52.16809       0.747591     3/4/2016  161     2           6
15  Customer_15   52.210014      0.892855     3/4/2016  29      2           4
0       DC        51.4457678    -0.45613      3/4/2016  0       0           6
0       DC        51.4457678    -0.45613      3/4/2016  0       1           4
0       DC        51.4457678    -0.45613      3/4/2016  0       2           8
```

Comment: Someone is more likely to help you if you post code and sample dataframe data. What have you tried, and what happened when you did? You posted your desired table format, but you didn't state why the first and last three rows are important and what differentiates them from the others.

Comment: Hi, the data frame is what I posted here. I thought it's clearer to show it rather than showing the code which is just basic data frame import process. My output is a list of lists indicating the routing plan for each vehicle which I want to convert them into the new data frame with two more columns indicating the vehicle assignment and positions in the assigned routes. The purpose is to help user to do some visualisation and analysis in Tabluea or PowerBI

Comment: Again, I suggest you post code that anyone reading your question can run. I would try out your code, find something that works, and then answer your question. I'm not going to write new code to recreate your dataframe. There are articles on stackoverflow.com about how to write good questions. See "How to Create a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/How-to-ask

Comment: I have added the sample input file which can be loaded as above data frame. hope it helps you. I cannot upload all my codes and they are irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way but for now this will do.

Construct the new columns:

```
df['Vehicle_ID'] = 0
df['Pos_in_route'] = 0
```

Create an empty dataframe: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)`

Let's say your output for vehicle assignment is:

```
veh =  [[0,8,3,6,11,13,0],[0,12,9,5,0],[0,4,7,10,15,1,14,2,0]]
```

To create `Vehicle_ID`, you want to map the rows by their indices to the vehicle ID. The following loop will look at every vehicle assignment list and create every but the last entry (ending at the terminal station).

```
for i in range(len(veh)):
    veh_id_dict = dict.fromkeys(veh[i][:-1],i)
    veh_pos_dict = dict(zip(veh[i][:-1],range(len(veh[i])-1)))
    df.loc[veh[i][:-1],'Vehicle_ID'] = df.loc[veh[i][:-1]].ID.map(veh_id_dict)
    df.loc[veh[i][:-1],'Pos_in_route'] = df.loc[veh[i][:-1]].ID.map(veh_pos_dict)
    df1 = df1.append(df.loc[veh[i][:-1]])
df1.sort_values(['ID','Vehicle_ID'],inplace =True)
```

Then we can construct the last few rows:

```
for i in range(len(veh)):
    df.loc[veh[i][-1],'Vehicle_ID'] = i
    df.loc[veh[i][-1],'Pos_in_route'] = len(veh[i]-1)
    df1 = df1.append(df.loc[veh[i][-1]])
```

Comment: Great thanks. overall it's working great but there is a small issue for the last few rows (the final position number of the DC is 1 unit bigger than the position number of the last delivery location). e.g. it the last delivery ends at position 7, the position of DC (last points) appended is 9 instead of 8.

Comment: Great thanks. overall it's working great but there is a small issue for the last few rows. Modification made for df.loc[veh[i][-1], 'Pos_in_route'] = len(veh[i])-1 will work perfectly